# How can I turn several json files into a dataframe?

Tags: json, dataframe, for-loop

I have some json files that needs to be turned into dataframes. So far, I created lists of names for dataframes, dat and .json file names with simple for loops as in the below:

```
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd
import os

match_id_required_l = ['7581', '7529', '8652', '7545', '8658', '7561', '8656'] 

file_name_l = [] 
for i in match_id_required_l: 
    j=str(i)+'.json' 
    file_name_l.append(j)

dataframes_l = []
for i in match_id_required_l: 
    j='df'+str(i) 
    dataframes_l.append(j)
    
data_l = []
for i in match_id_required_l: 
    j='data'+str(i) 
    data_l.append(j)

json_file_l = []
for i in match_id_required_l: 
    j='json_file'+str(i) 
    json_file_l.append(j)
```

I tried to open them all up as json file and turn them into dataframes with another for loop but failed, as obviously I am making a mistake so that it gives "too many values to unpack" error. The below is the for loop that I gave it a try:

```
for i, j in file_name_l, json_file_l:
    with open('XXX/data/YYY/'+i, errors='ignore') as j:
        for n, j in data_l, json_file_l:
            n = json.load(j)
```

The files names that I try to open up are correct, I checked them out manually. Curious about how to fix it, as it is not ideal to open them up one by one. Many thanks in advance for the support!

Comment: probably in python ?

Comment: yes, sorry for forgetting to make it clear.

Comment: so dataframes is pandas ? you should share some code as there might be some ways to do that. I.g. Load the json as array of dicts or with pandas or....

Comment: Just edited my question, I think this is much more explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly Load json in Pandas Data Frames like that

```
import pandas as pd
df_data_1 = pd.read_json("filepath_data1.json")
```

You can merge dataframes in pandas like that

```
result = pd.merge(df_data_1, df_data_2 , on='COLUMN_NAME', how='outer')
```

also you want to tag your questions here with the library names you use in your code. Please always post a minimal reduceable example

Comment: Thanks a lot! the reason I tried to do like that was actually I had to json_normalize() it while converting them into data frames.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is now, sorry